# Manyrelatedmanager method all() returns empty in m2m relationship

Tags: django-models

I am a beginner to django framework and have been struggling to get attributes in m2m relationship.

Simple m2m model works fine where intermediate table for m2m relation is automatically created by django. But, my requirement is to use an existing mysql db where 3 tables scripts, testbed and script_testbed exists.

in python shell, when I perform below commands, i get a empty list.

```
>>> from smapp.models import Script
>>> b = Script.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b.testbeds.all()
[]
```

My Model.py looks like:

```
class Testbed(models.Model):
    tb_id = models.IntegerField()
    tb_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tb_platform = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def publish(self):
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tb_name
    class Meta:
        db_table = "testbeds"  # Table name in db is testbeds.

class Script(models.Model):
    script_id = models.IntegerField()
    script_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    testbeds = models.ManyToManyField(Testbed,     through='ScriptsTestbed')
    def publish(self):
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.script_name
    class Meta:
        db_table = "scripts"   # Table name in db is testbeds.

class ScriptTestbed(models.Model):
    scripts = models.ForeignKey(Script, db_column='script_id') #script_id is the column name in db table.
    testbed = models.ForeignKey(Testbed, db_column='testbed_id') #testbed_id is the column name in db table.
    def publish(self):
        self.save()
    def __int__(self):
        return self.script_id
    class Meta:
        db_table = "scripts_testbed" #Table name in db is scripts_testbed
```

Simple m2m example of author & book works well for me. Only difference I see is that the db already exists and I am missing some basic settings.

Any suggestion is appreciated.